# cant play an animation when pressing a button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[screen shot of the animator panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B35LN.png)

so as you can see I am trying to play an animation called Attack when triggering the parameter Attack but whenever I press the triggering button that I chose the animation just doesn't work and the trigger does not get activated

here is my code

> ```
> using System.Collections;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using UnityEngine;
>
> public class attack : MonoBehaviour
> {
>     public Animator animator;
>
>     void Update()
>     {
>         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
>         {
>             Attack();
>         }
>     }
>
>     void Attack()
>     {
>         animator.SetTrigger("Attack");
>     }
> }
> ```

by the way, I am trying to follow this guy's video

https://youtu.be/sPiVz1k-fEs

Comment: Do you have warnings in console during play mode?

Comment: Did you assign the trigger to be the cause to trigger the animation in the animator?  Are you sure it’s Attack and not say lower case etc

Comment: I don't have any errors and its clear in the screenshot that I have assigned the trigger to be the cause to trigger the animation

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestions:**

> 1. Make sure you have assigned this script to a game object.

> 2. Assign the right animator that you want to animate in inspector of this script.

> 3. Check if you have added 'Attack' parameter in that animator and the spelling is same like the one mentioned as parameter in your code.

> 4. and lastly check if you have set the trigger for the transition of animation in the animator( in animator its the arrow that is pointing towards your animation ).

**Let me know if you don't understand any of this I'll breifly explain.**

Hopefully that will help... Happy coding :)

Comment: if u can see the screenshot u can see that I have all of that checked 